# Add image above the video with ffmepg

Tags: ffmpeg

Apologies for being a ffmpeg noob, but I'm having trouble with modifying the answer to

[Add image under the video with ffmepg](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14519/add-image-under-the-video-with-ffmepg/14532#14532?newreg=4a36ee24267d464390a1582c3b5f3221)

to place the image above instead of below the video...

My questions is in regard to modifying the command

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=320:-1[bottom];[0:v][bottom]vstack" output.mp4
```

I tried many different variations of this command to no avail and I think its my misunderstand of filter_complex and the meaning of "[1:v]" "[bottom]" and "[0:v]"

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic form will be

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=320:-1[top];[top][0:v]vstack" output.mp4
```

A label of the form `1:v`, equivalent to `1:v:0` within filters, is a stream specifier - it means use the first video stream of the 2nd input. `0:v` refers to the first video stream of the first input.

The `bottom` in your command and `top` in mine are arbitrary labels assigned to the result of the scale filter.

Then that resulting stream is fed first to the vstack so that it gets stacked on top.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Now looking at it it seems so clear but you have no idea how many different orderings of the first command that I tried to no avail!